# Portlet - passing parameter from render phase to resource phase

Tags: java, portlet

Is it possible to copy some values from render (or better action) phase to resource path?

It is possible to pass parameter from action phase to render phase as described in the Liferay Documentation: [Passing Information from the Action Phase to the Render Phase](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-phase).

I think that using the session for this is not feasible because of browsing in multiple tabs...

Also using ThreadLocal is not possible (it's not the same thread).

Any ideas? I'd like to track AJAX calls (resource phase) with initial user action (action phase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render parameters on page and then send AJAX requests with these parameters. You also can create static class with map session id => parameters. And render on page session id, pass it back to server when you send AJAX request and retrieve parameters from map.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I think first one will work, but I have hundred of pages and do not know how to modify all these pages. Second hint with map won't work I think, same problem as with storing it into the session.

Comment: When the user uses more than one tab in browser, session is the same. So when user performs some action in one tab (and later some AJAX calls are called) and in second tab (also some AJAX calls are called), I'm not able to track AJAX calls with performed action using session (which is the same while user actions are not).

Comment: Ok. You can than generate your own "session-tab" id and pass it to page. But in this way you need to modify every page.